# log4j writes blank lines in console

Tags: eclipse, logging, log4j

I have the following log4j configuration:

```
<appender name="MYCONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
  <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
  <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601}|%-5p|MYAPP|%t|%C{1}.%M(%L)|%m%n"/>
  </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="MYFILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/myapp.log"/>
  <param name="Append" value="true"/>
  <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>

  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601}|%-5p|MYAPP|%t|%C{1}.%M(%L)|%m%n"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

In the Eclipse console, every log line produced by this configuration is followed by a completely blank line:

```
12:46:27,289 INFO  [stdout] 2017-01-25 12:46:27,289|INFO|MYAPP|something

12:46:27,289 INFO  [stdout] 2017-01-25 12:46:27,289|INFO|MYAPP|something else
```

This happens only with logs generated by MYCONSOLE, all other logs (such as the internal JBoss's ones) don't have blank lines.
Also, in the MYFILE log file, the logs are the same but the blank lines are not there.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to get rid of the extra lines by using `\n` instead of `%n`.

The reason of the strange behaviour of `%n` is still not clear to me.

Comment: Been searching for this answer for a looooong time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Getting same to me when I use consoleAppader for audit logger

```
log4j.appender.audit=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.audit.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.audit.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.audit.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601}|%t|%m%n
```

The logs dumping on console are empty/blank lines.

If I remove I can get rid of empty lines, I am missing actual data too.
Would appreciate any pointers

Comment: Since I am reading audit log, I need to change PatternLayout  to Audit Layout , Aftre adding below audit logs are able to  print propeorly. 
```log4j.appender.audit.layout=org.apache.knox.gateway.audit.log4j.layout.AuditLayout```